# Does BTRFS raid 10, support the failure of 2 devices?

Tags: btrfs, raid

[According to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555885/3285)

> The guarantee that BTRFS offers, which makes it looks like regular raid 10, is that each piece of data is guaranteed to exist on two distinct drives, so the filesystem will survive a failure of a single drive. **What it does not offer compared to regular raid 10 is that if two drives fail, you most likely have lost your filesystem, whereas regular raid 10 can survive if the two failed drives are in different clusters.**

Is this true? And if it is true, what is the advantage of Raid 10? I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the official wiki or documentation? How should I think about the redundancy offered by BTRFS's Raid 10 as it relates to device failure?

Answer (score 1):

This is true because BTRFS implements policies such as RAID10 on a fine grained chunk level rather than device-level.

In one chunk you could survive two disk failures just like classical RAID10 could on whole devices but one chunk is only 1GiB in most cases. As soon as you have written more than 1GiB into the filesystem, different parts of the data will tolerate different combinations of secondary disk failures; meaning that, in all likelyhood, you'll lose the availability of at least some part of your data while other data remains available.
Given that metadata and data are in separate chunk groups, you will have at least two chunks in a btrfs that contains any data.

Relying on the possibility of surviving two disk failures of classical RAID10 is rather questionable though. You'd be well advised to only expect resistance against one failure in either case.